# Bing map silverlight control change mode of operation.

Tags: silverlight, bing-maps

By default map viewer responds to map click with dragging map around viewer. I'd like to create functionality wher user can click, draw rectangle and map zooms into this rectangle.

Is this supported by map or is there any way to achieve such behavior?

Answer (score 0):

[Adding Shapes to bing map](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee681899.aspx)
 and after adding the shape you can change the zoom level of the map

Comment: I don't see how it helps. I want to click on map (hold mouse button), draw rectangle and let map zoom to this rectangle